# Configure Tooltip Content Template Declaratively

Tags: kendo-ui, tooltip

Is it possible configure a Kendo UI tooltip's content template when using the data- declarative syntax.

The following would simple create a tooltip using the word `template` as the content.

```
<div data-role="tooltip" data-content="template">
   Lorum ipsum....
</div>
```

Comment: But a tooltip should refer to some element, how do you plan to say which element? What is your final goal?

Comment: When you use the `data-` declarative syntax it adds the tooltip to the element you put the `data-` attribute in. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/ANOcEMU/1/edit

Comment: The problem with the example is that I cannot use `data-content` to configure a template. If I put `data-content='#template-id'` the the tooltip just contains the literal text #template-id.

Comment: But in JS initialization you actually are not using a template either. It is either a string, a function returning a string or jQuery expression that return the html as string butt always a string. What you basically need is getting the content of the template.

Comment: That makes sense. So I suppose the answer should be "No" followed by your comment above. At least until the Kendo team adds a `template` option. Would you be kind enough to put your comment as an answer and I will select it?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but I don't know if it is actually usable since doing it this way, you should have the element to which it refers inside the element.

For initializing it, you should have a JavaScript like:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        kendo.init($("body"));
    });
</script>
```

And then your HTML is fine.

Or you can have an HTML little more complex like:

```html
<div>
    <ol data-role="tooltip" data-content="message" data-filter="li>span">
        <li><span>item 1</span></li>
        <li><span>item 22</span></li>
        <li><span>item 333</span></li>
        <li><span>item 4444</span></li>
        <li><span>item 55555</span></li>
        <li><span>item 666666</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/GerEN/

You can also use something like:

```html
<div>
    <ol data-role="tooltip" data-content="{ url : 'url.html'} " data-filter="li>span">
        <li><span>item 1</span></li>
        <li><span>item 22</span></li>
        <li><span>item 333</span></li>
        <li><span>item 4444</span></li>
        <li><span>item 55555</span></li>
        <li><span>item 666666</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Where you pass a `content.url` for retrieving the actual content.

Comment: The problem is that I want the tooltip to contain markup. Not just a text string.

Answer (score 0):

The data-content tag can take HTML as it's property meaning you can avoid using a separate content tempate:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    data-content="<div style='text-align: left; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;'><p>MVVM Property: #= mvvmPropertyName #</p></div>" 
</script>
```

Hope this helps.